# Issue using Apache tika parser when trying to parse pdf having text contains image

Tags: java, scala, apache-tika, runtimeexception, pdfparser

I am using these two dependencies:-
tika core 2.6.0
tika parser standard package 2.6.0
.Parsing is working fine for these cases:-
pdf file with text.
pdf file with images.
text files and other extensions.

Parsing is failing with pdfparser runtime exception for the use case below:-
pdf file with text inside images.

Can someone pls suggest how to resolve failed case here. Thanks

Full error Stack trace:-

org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException from org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser@2d539b25
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:312) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-core-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:298) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-core-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:175) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-core-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.AbstractPDF2XHTML.doOCROnCurrentPage(AbstractPDF2XHTML.java:520) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-parsers-standard-package-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.AbstractPDF2XHTML.endPage(AbstractPDF2XHTML.java:786) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-parsers-standard-package-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.endPage(PDF2XHTML.java:154) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-parsers-standard-package-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:365) ~[org.apache.pdfbox.pdfbox-2.0.27.jar:2.0.27]
at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.processPage(PDF2XHTML.java:137) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-parsers-standard-package-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.AbstractPDF2XHTML.processPages(AbstractPDF2XHTML.java:1277) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-parsers-standard-package-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:238) ~[org.apache.pdfbox.pdfbox-2.0.27.jar:2.0.27]
at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.process(PDF2XHTML.java:108) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-parsers-standard-package-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:198) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-parsers-standard-package-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:298) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-core-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
... 37 more

Comment: What's the exception you get?

Comment: 500 internal server error:- org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected Runtime exception from org.apache.parser.pdf.PDFParser@12345

Comment: This issue is not there if we use tika-parsers 1.28.5 and tika-core 1.28.5. As part of moving to the upgraded version. I need to update these versions to 1.2.60 and follow the modular approach in Tika we have currently.

Comment: Not able to update the above comment. this is the exception @Gagravarr . org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException from org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser@350ab3f1

Comment: Can you provide more of the stacktrace?  Is that your server error or ours in tika-server?

Comment: Hi @TimAllison, this is tika error i am getting from PDF Parser. i will see if i can get the whole stack trace.

Comment: Hi Tim, this is the whole stack trace :- org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException from org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser@2d539b25
 at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:312) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-core-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
 at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:298) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-core-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
 at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:175) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-core-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.AbstractPDF2XHTML.doOCROnCurrentPage(AbstractPDF2XHTML.java:520) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-parsers-standard-package-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
 at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.AbstractPDF2XHTML.endPage(AbstractPDF2XHTML.java:786) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-parsers-standard-package-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
 at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.endPage(PDF2XHTML.java:154) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-parsers-standard-package-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]

Comment: at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:365) ~[org.apache.pdfbox.pdfbox-2.0.27.jar:2.0.27]
 at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.processPage(PDF2XHTML.java:137) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-parsers-standard-package-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
 at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.AbstractPDF2XHTML.processPages(AbstractPDF2XHTML.java:1277) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-parsers-standard-package-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
 at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:238) ~[org.apache.pdfbox.pdfbox-2.0.27.jar:2.0.27]

Comment: at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.process(PDF2XHTML.java:108) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-parsers-standard-package-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
 at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:198) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-parsers-standard-package-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
 at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:298) ~[org.apache.tika.tika-core-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
 ... 37 more

Comment: please note that same code will work fine if i change the dependenices from tika-parser-standard-package 2.6.0 to tika-parsers-1.28.5 and tika-core-2.6.0 to tika-core-1.28.5

Comment: Issue is fixed now. Its expecting Parser.class instance for scanned images.I have passed that in context. Thanks

Comment: @DeadPool do we need to install tesseract ocr engine separately or adding tika core and tika parser is enough??

Comment: @Seriously sorry for the delay reply. Yes we need to install tesseract on the top of tika parser and core and also to set path configurations if required.

Answer (score 0):

You should use different PDFParserConfig
There are 2 types of pdfs files

1. native files (also called searchble) - Tika is able to extract text from native without ocr

   PDFParserConfig pdfParserConfig = new PDFParserConfig();

   pdfParserConfig.setExtractInlineImages(false);

   pdfParserConfig.setOcrStrategy(NO_OCR);
2. scanned files (or images converted to pdf) - Tika has to do the OCR (using the tesseract under the hood)

   PDFParserConfig pdfParserConfig = new PDFParserConfig();

   pdfParserConfig.setExtractInlineImages(true);

   pdfParserConfig.setOcrStrategy(OCR_ONLY);

Comment: Currently i am using this configuration:-
    pdfParserConfig.setExtractInlineImages(true)
    pdfParserConfig.setExtractUniqueInlineImagesOnly(true)
It is working fine for text inside pdf, images inside pdf but failing for embedded text inside image in pdf.
if i update the conf to:-
    pdfParserConfig.setExtractInlineImages(true)
    pdfParserConfig.setExtractUniqueInlineImagesOnly(true)
   pdfParserConfig.setOcrStrategy(PDFParserConfig.OCR_STRATEGY.OCR_ONLY)
Its failing for all types of pdf files.

Comment: I m using both. the first attempt is to extract text from pdf without OCR. It works for native/searchable pdfs. If it works I return extracted text. In not I know that the file is a scan and OCR is required.  This is the best solution that I ve found so far.

Comment: Hi Merek, May i know which dependencies and their versions you are using. I have done the second point implementation and trying with scanned files only. Its giving the same error.

Comment: Issue is fixed now. Its expecting Parser.class instance for scanned images.I have passed that in context. Thanks